# db2 Long running SQL with IDLE status and connections UOW Waiting

Tags: sql, performance, db2, query-optimization

In my Db2 LUW 11.1 environment, I have a connected application once a day that performs a simple select * from TABLE with ur; (I did not include the name of the board for security)
Normally this query made by the user instance is performed by 3ms, but by a technician user at a specific time of the day it is already about half an hour. What steps should be taken to thoroughly investigate the cause. I tried explain and db2batch for this query, which gave me the effect that the query only scans the table and nothing else and batch shows that the query is done in 3ms. When examining the query while it is being processed, I can see that it has the status of UOWAIT and from time to time it reads new data, and most of the time it is IDLE. How to measure it to understand what the cause of the problem is

Answer (score 1):

If you know the application handle (`xxx` below), you may start with the following to understand what happens in the session.

The table functions used in these queries contain a lot of columns. Refer to the corresponding links for the details. You may add other ones if you need them.
[MON_GET_AGENT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=mpf-mon-get-agent-list-agents-fenced-mode-processes-system-entities-database)
[MON_GET_UNIT_OF_WORK](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=mpf-mon-get-unit-work-get-unit-work-metrics)
[MON_GET_ACTIVITY](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-mon-get-activity-return-list-activities)
[MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0055017.html)

```
-- Agents working for the application
SELECT 
  UOW_ID, ACTIVITY_ID
, EVENT_STATE, EVENT_TYPE, EVENT_OBJECT
FROM TABLE (MON_GET_AGENT (NULL, NULL, xxx, -2))
;

-- Transaction statistics
SELECT 
  WORKLOAD_OCCURRENCE_STATE
, UOW_ID
, PREV_UOW_STOP_TIME, UOW_START_TIME, UOW_STOP_TIME
, ROWS_READ, ROWS_RETURNED
FROM TABLE (MON_GET_UNIT_OF_WORK (xxx, -2))
;

-- List of all application activities
SELECT 
  A.UOW_ID, A.ACTIVITY_ID, A.ACTIVITY_STATE
, A.TOTAL_ACT_TIME, A.TOTAL_ACT_WAIT_TIME  
, P.ROWS_READ, P.ROWS_RETURNED, P.STMT_TEXT
FROM 
  TABLE (MON_GET_ACTIVITY (xxx, -2)) A
, TABLE (MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT (NULL, A.EXECUTABLE_ID, NULL, A.MEMBER)) P
;
```

The situation you describe may happen, for example, when the application has opened a cursor and is fetching rows slowly...

Comment: I executed these commands, however there is no information there that the target table from my query has been blocked. The first query to check application activity showed that EVENT_STATE: IDLE
EVENT_TYPE: WAIT
EVENT_OBJECT: REQUEST

Comment: It seems that this application does nothing and after some time it disappears from the server. Can I assume that the problem is somewhere on the side of the application that has the wrong configuration

Comment: If an application is IDLE for a long time, its activity counters are not incremented, then it's highly likely, that the application "forgot" to end the transaction / close a cursor. It may be sudden application termination / network problem as well, and the server may terminate the corresponding session after a while only.

Comment: This application doesn`t open a cursor, it is just a select * from table with ur. I see that the application has the IDLE status and the thread on the Db2 side does nothing.

Comment: And the situation is that the user from his application releases this query and doesn`t get a response until after an hour, or at the best time of half an hour. It also happens that the user interrupts the query and releases it again, and then it ends immediately, and after a while the problem reappears. I wonder if the problem lies with the mechanism responsible for the connection pool or agents. I will add that the problem only occurs during rush hours and it didn`t appear when I ran the query from the instance user

Comment: What's the result of the last statement in my answer? Do you see this select statement in the result?